# Submit html form to PDF without database

Tags: php, jquery, html, dompdf

Without a database support can I directly convert an HTML form into a PDF file when someone submits their data.
The given below is my current status.
If I have div with id myform

```
<div id="myform">
    <h1>My form</h1>
    <form action=" " method="post">
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Grab form html code.

```
var form = $("#myform").html();
```

But the variable *form* will not contain any user data with *value* attributes

My expected output is.

```
<h1>My form</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="some-userdata-entered-just-now">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value ="some-userdata-entered-just-now">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I am planning to put this HTML into dompdf for generate a PDF file.
Is there any way? Please help.

Comment: OP has not receiving in html with `<input value="some"` which is entered now. try my answer and demo

Comment: Do you just want to render a PDF of the filled out form? Or do you want to capture the responses and use those to render a new HTML document to PDF? The latter may work better (e.g. you don't have to worry as much about truncated text in the PDF where the form elements are not large enough).

Comment: Hi BrianS, I just want a simple HTML form, when I filled out and submit need to get a new PDF of the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
    $("#myform input:text").each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $(this).attr("value", val);
    });

    var form = $("#myform").html();
    alert(form);
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G89mX/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

There's a great client-side solution here: http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

You can find it on Github: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

If you use JavaScript to grab the values from the form, you can put those into the PDF and save it using the methods shown in the examples here: http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TCPDF. TCPDF is a free and open source software PHP class for generating PDF documents. TCPDF is the only PHP-based library that includes complete support for UTF-8 Unicode and right-to-left languages, including the bidirectional algorithm.

visit that link for more information. http://www.tcpdf.org/